# Having animate_process() highlight where things are currently at instead of just pushing everything to END

Tags: r, bupar

Is there a way to use animateProcess and not have everything at the END node.  We want to visualize a live process where things are still happening.  We have visualized some log data and everything should end at an event called closed.  In the map everything currently goes from closed to end but many records are still actively moving through the process.  Those are simply moving from there active state to the END and skipping the subsequent steps.  Any suggestions on showing where records are currently at?

Using the example code from bupaverse Github

library(processanimateR)
library(eventdataR)

animate_process(patients, mode = "relative", jitter = 10, legend = "color", mapping = token_aes(color = token_scale("employee",scale = "ordinal", range = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(7, "Paired"))))

If you run this script you'll notice that in this example there are a few cases when the patient goes from Triage and Assessment to end.  I'm guessing these patients are still in the process of checking out and just haven't completed there process.  I run into the same issue in my instance where everyone is "forced" to the end despite there being cases that are actively progressing towards the end.  Trying to figured out how to hold the point on the spot that it is actively stuck on.

TLDR:  I have incomplete cases in my process and I'm looking for a way to show that they are incomplete in the animate_process.  They default to going to the end of the process.

Looked through documentation and didn't see an option for this.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What does your current code look like?

Comment: @MrFlick hopefully the above him work for a better example of what I'm experiencing and what I hope to change.  Thank you